# Defining strings to be used across Blazor app

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Blazor component project that would automatically build a menu for the user. In this project I have public strings that are used to pass the css class items into the html elements.

So I want to achieve is that the user would define the css for each string that is then referenced in the component itself and then would be used by the component to properly build the menu. From researching this, it appears the best way to do this would be to create a class with all the definitions:

```
public static class GlobalDefinitions {
     public const string FirstCSS = "some-CSS-stuff-here";
     public const string SecondCSS = "some-CSS-stuff-here";
}
```

But I am not sure how this would incorporated into the component building itself. The page itself is just going to use `@using My.Menu` at the top to import the component in. The menu building itself:

```
<MyMenu>
  <MyMenuItem>
    <NavLink href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</NavLink>
  </MyMenuItem>
  <MySubMenu Header="Sub Menu">
        <MenuTemplate>
            <MyMenuItem>
                <NavLink href="counter">Counter</NavLink>
            </MyMenuItem>
        </MenuTemplate>
    </MySubMenu>
    <MyMenuItem>
        <NavLink href="fetchdata">Fetch data</NavLink>
    </MyMenuItem>
</MyMenu>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is to use a Razor Class Library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class) to create a CSS file inside a reusable assembly, then on your Blazor component you just reference the CSS file as you normally would.